# Google Maps nearby people, and custom lists

Tags: google-maps

I'm not familiar with the Google Docs API yet but this is what I want to do:

First people sign up on my webpage and in the profile specify in which town they live.
How can I then do so other people can search for nearby people (and specify max distance) using the Google Maps API?

Thx
Jocke

Answer (score 0):

You [obtain the geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en) of your users and [calculate the distance](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) between them.

Comment: Excellent, thank you Joachim.

Anyone that can point me to an example? Or just a similar code?